# Serial port is stuck at wait(4,

Tags: c++, linux, serial-port

I have this implementation in C++ for linux for initializing a serial port:

```
void setupSerialPort()
{
    fcntl(STDIN_FILENO, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);       

    memset(&tio, 0, sizeof(tio));
    tio.c_iflag = 0;
    tio.c_oflag = 0;
    tio.c_cflag = CS8|CREAD|CLOCAL;                 
    tio.c_lflag = 0;
    tio.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;                             
    tio.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;                                

    fd = open(SERIALPORT, O_RDWR | O_NONBLOCK) ;                

    fcntl(fd , F_SETFL, 0);     // read data in the buffer per chunk

    cfsetospeed(&tio, B4800);             // 4800 baud
    cfsetispeed(&tio, B4800);             // 4800 baud

    tcsetattr(fd , TCSANOW, &tio);
}
```

Sometimes, the serial port reading is stuck and I use 'strace' to see what is going on. the problem is:

```
strace -p 9454
Process 9454 attached - interrupt to quit
wait4(-1, ^C <unfinished ...>
Process 9454 detached
```

How can I avoid the problem (it does not happen all the time)?

Comment: Where exactly does it get stuck? What driver handles that serial port?

Comment: it stucks something here: wait4(-1, ^C <unfinished ...>, it is a gps device

Comment: but it does not happen all the same

Comment: Have you tried debugging to find where it's stuck in your code?

Comment: Compile it with -g flag and use debugger instead. use bt in gdb to display backtrace once it is stuck and from where was it called. By the way, are you sure fd and serialPort_fd should not be the same variable? Are you checking error results for each call? You would not even know something failed in this code.

Comment: @Pihhan I assumed that was a simple copy & paste error, but since these variables seem be static scoped, maybe you're on to something.

Comment: @Pihhan sorry, serialport_fd and fd is the same variable

Comment: `9454` looks like the wrong process id.  That is probably the parent process (perhaps a shell) which is waiting for your process.

Comment: Where is `tio` defined and why do you `fcntl(STDIN_FILENO)` in `setupSerialPort()`?

Comment: @mark4o that is how to do check it with strace in multi-threading

Comment: @OlafDietsche tio is defined as a global variable. I found a sample somewhere that I need to set: fcntl, no?

Comment: @olidev I just asked, because stdin and the serial port are unrelated and this function is named `setupSerialPort` and not `setupSerialPortAndStdin` ;-)

Comment: Where does it stuck exactly in your code? Also, what serial port do you use: real or some kind of emulation?

Comment: What does strace() spew look like in the successful case?

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurring randomly indicates that the call to open is failing. So check the return values from open call and other remaining calls.

`if (fd < 0) return;`

Also ensure clean close of the serial port.

Comment: how can I ensure clean close of the serial port? Thanks

Comment: You can ensure clean close by close(fd) in the exit path of your program. If 'fd' is local to function, then close(fd) should work at the end of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Syscalls involving IO could get stuck specially with network IO. Since you are using NON_BLOCKING mode that shouldnt be the case , The complete code  would have been helpful here. Personally i had this situation before and I used timer to generate SIG_USR which used to end the blocking call with an error. Pseudo code for that algo is as follows:

```
 initiateTimer ( timeout)
     myfunctionCall(){
        someSysCall();
     }
  if(!signalled){
    disableTimer();
  }else{
     checkState();
     if(fatal)
       die;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestions... Open the device with:

int fd = TEMP_FAILURE_RETRY(open(ttyName, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NONBLOCK));

The macro TEMP_FAILURE_RETRY is needed to protect open, close, read and select from signal interruptions. Read about the macro if you use libc. Include O_NOCTTY flag to avoid the device becoming the controlling port of the process. Check return value for valid fd.

---

C.